# Conditionals with possible None values in List comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, conditional-operator, nonetype

I have a `xml` file that lists speakers:

```
<speakerlist>
    <speaker>
        <title>Dr.</titel>
        <firstname>Bernd</firstname>
        <lastname>Baumann</lastname>
    </speaker>
    <speakerid="11003218">
        <firstname>Karsten</firstname>
        <lastname>Schneider</lastname>
        <info>(Erfurt)</info>
    </speaker>
    ...
<speakerlist>
```

Some of the speaker attributes are always given (`firstname`, `lastname`) while others are optional (`title`, `info`). I want to extract the names with the additional info in a straightforward way.

Just the name is easy, using beatifulsoup:

```py
[speaker.find("firstname").text + " " +  speaker.find("lastname").text for speaker in speakerlist.find_all("speaker")]
```

But how can I prepend the `title` if existing? I tried

```py
[
    speaker.find("title").text + " " + speaker.find("firstname").text + " " + speaker.find("lastname").text 
    if speaker.find("title").text is not None 
    else speaker.find("firstname").text + " " +  speaker.find("lastname").text
    for speaker in speakerlist.find_all("speaker")
]
```

but this throws

```py
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

when the `title` attribute does not exist. I understand why this happens, but I don't see a workaround.

Is there a nice and cohesive way for a one-liner to extract the information I want?

Comment: whenever you execute an instruction susceptible to fail you should put it inside a `try` statement, so you can capture any exceptions it might throw and handle them accordingly

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki ... and you can't put try/except in an expression, such as a list comprehension.

Comment: that's why sometimes compacting the code in a single line is not the best solution, specially when dealing with data that might be dirty. Either clean the data before or handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no good reason to try and squeeze this into an "one-liner" list comprehension.

```
def format_speaker_record(speaker):
    title_tag = speaker.find("title")
    title = (title.text if title_tag else None)
    firstname = speaker.find("firstname").text
    lastname = speaker.find("lastname").text
    if title:
        return f"{title} {firstname} {lastname}"
    return f"{firstname} {lastname}"


speakers = [format_speaker_record(speaker) for speaker in speakerlist.find_all("speaker")]
```